# Upermitted parameters "thing" in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I need to permit these parameters in a Controller but fail to find the correct way.I dont see how 
[documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) helps..
Is there any online tools that does this automatically and does not require such rails mapping puzzles ?

```
  def sort
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    logger.debug "parameters on sort method of line items: #{params.inspect}"
    # .attributes is a useful shorthand for mass-assigning
    # values via a hash
    #@line_item.attributes = params[:thing]
    @line_item.update!(sort_params)
    render :nothing =>true
  end



   def sort_params
      params.permit(:id, :thing=>[] )
    end
```

---

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"2", "thing"=>{"insert_at"=>"0"}}
```

This is the ajax call to the controller:

```
  # Sorting with Bootstrap
  # this is a small hack; when a tr is dragged with jQuery UI sortable
  # the cells lose their width
  cells = $('.table').find('tr')[0].cells.length
  desired_width = 940 / cells + 'px'
  $('.table td').css('width', desired_width)

  $('#sortable').sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    items: '.item'

    # highlight the row on drop to indicate an update
    stop: (e, ui) ->
      ui.item.children('td').effect('highlight', {}, 1000)
    update: (e, ui) ->
      item_id = ui.item.data('item-id')
      position = ui.item.index()
      $.ajax(
        type: 'POST'       
        url: $(this).data('update-url')
        dataType: 'json'
        # the :thing hash gets passed to @thing.attributes
        # row_order is the default column name expected in ranked-model
        data: { id: item_id, thing: { insert_at: position } }           
      )
  )
```

Comment: Are you sure your parameters are not englobbed in a "LineItem" key ?

Comment: Processing by LineItemsController#sort as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2", "thing"=>{"insert_at"=>"0"}}

Comment: The new result after the answer is  :TypeError (can't convert Symbol into String):
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:55:in `sort_params'